# SQL Query to show multiple entries and its count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table like this (just look at Col1 and Col2)

```
ID   Col1   Col2   Col3
1    1a     2b     vewva
2    1a     2b     ds33
3    1c     2d     sadp
4    1c     2e     c2w
5    1c     2d     2309v
6    1d     2f     2fd3
7    1c     2d     23d3
```

I need to find duplicates in (Col1, Col2).

What I need is some output like this:

```
1a 2b --> occurred 2 times
1c 2d --> occurred 3 times
```

Is there a SQL Query that can produce that?
Including sort by (or group by) Col2 if possible.

(I'm not sure what the database version is, but it's Microsoft SQL Server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select col1, col2, count(*)
from yourTable
group by col1, col2
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try

```
select count(*) as c, col1, col2 from foobar group by col1, col2 having c > 1
```